Sorting an array of objects by date with some dates being null
I have a huge array of objects called steamData that look like this:
 {
        "sid": 1690,
        "store_url": "https://store.steampowered.com/app/1690",
        "store_promo_url": null,
        "store_uscore": 69,
        "published_store": "2006-10-16",
        "published_meta": "2006-10-16",
        "published_stsp": "2006-10-16",
        "published_hltb": "2020-04-18",
        "published_igdb": "2006-09-01",
        "image": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/1690/header.jpg",
        "name": "Space Empires V",
        "description": "Space Empires V is the latest edition in the Space Empires series. This new chapter completely updates the UI and takes ...",
        "full_price": 1999,
        "current_price": 499,
        "discount": 75,
        "platforms": "WIN",
        "developers": "Malfador Machinations",
        "publishers": "Strategy First",
        "languages": "English",
        "voiceovers": null,
        "categories": "Single-player,Multi-player",
        "genres": "Strategy",
        "tags": "Strategy,4X,Space,Sci-fi,Turn-Based,Singleplayer,Turn-Based Strategy,Multiplayer",
        "achievements": null,
        "gfq_url": "https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/927958-space-empires-v?ftag=MCD-06-10aaa1f",
        "gfq_difficulty": "Just Right-Tough",
        "gfq_difficulty_comment": "<a href=\"/games/rankings?platform=19&amp;genre=45&amp;list_type=diff&amp;dlc=1&amp;page=22&amp;game_id=927958&amp;min_votes=2#1114\"><b>#1114</b></a> hardest PC strategy game (<a href=\"/games/rankings?platform=19&amp;list_type=diff&amp;dlc=1&amp;page=122&amp;game_id=927958&amp;min_votes=2#6145\"><b>#6145</b></a> on PC, <b>#24997</b> overall)",
        "gfq_rating": 3.54,
        "gfq_rating_comment": "<a href=\"/games/rankings?platform=19&amp;genre=45&amp;list_type=rate&amp;view_type=1&amp;dlc=1&amp;page=16&amp;game_id=927958&amp;min_votes=2#818\"><b>#818</b></a> lowest rated PC strategy game (<a href=\"/games/rankings?platform=19&amp;list_type=rate&amp;view_type=1&amp;dlc=1&amp;page=163&amp;game_id=927958&amp;min_votes=2#8199\"><b>#8199</b></a> on PC, <b>#33932</b> overall)",
        "gfq_length": 68.6,
        "gfq_length_comment": "<a href=\"/games/rankings?platform=19&amp;genre=45&amp;list_type=time&amp;dlc=1&amp;page=2&amp;game_id=927958&amp;min_votes=2#119\"><b>#119</b></a> longest PC strategy game (<a href=\"/games/rankings?platform=19&amp;list_type=time&amp;dlc=1&amp;page=12&amp;game_id=927958&amp;min_votes=2#618\"><b>#618</b></a> on PC, <b>#1757</b> overall)",
        "stsp_owners": 75000,
        "stsp_mdntime": null,
        "hltb_url": "https://howlongtobeat.com/game?id=8846",
        "hltb_single": 10,
        "hltb_complete": null,
        "meta_url": "https://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/space-empires-v?ftag=MCD-06-10aaa1f",
        "meta_score": 68,
        "meta_uscore": 77,
        "grnk_score": 65,
        "igdb_url": "https://www.igdb.com/games/space-empires-v",
        "igdb_single": null,
        "igdb_complete": null,
        "igdb_score": 65,
        "igdb_uscore": 50,
        "igdb_popularity": 1.89
    },

I'm trying to sort this array by it's published_meta date newest to oldest:
 if (!loading) {
    // Sort from oldest to youngest
    steamData.sort((a, b) => (b)?.published_meta.localeCompare((a)?.published_meta));

    // Get today as milliseconds
    let today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
    let todayMS = Date.parse(today);

    // Get index of closest element to today
    let closestIndex = steamData.reduce((acc, obj, index) => {
      let diff = Math.abs(Date.parse(obj?.published_meta) - todayMS);
      return acc.diff > diff ? { diff, index } : acc;
    }, { diff: Infinity, index: null }).index;

    // Move closest element to start of array
    steamData.unshift(newTrending.splice(closestIndex, 1));
  }

I keep running into the error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'localeCompare')"
Some of the objects are have null as their published dates (published_meta seems to have the fewest of these). I thought optional chaining would fix this but it has not.
How can I sort the steamData array to use?

You are optionally chaining to check b exists, the ?. goes after the property that might be null/undefined.

For this question 90% of the properties in that example object are irrelevant. Please, instead give an example with tiny objects, and instead provide several of them, and make it such that this array can be used to reproduce the problem. And please explain what you want to happen with these null entries.


Just fill null values with a fake string (if you need null values at top, change to 3 for example).
Don't use localeCompare since it's very slow, creates Intl.Collator every time. You characters are just digits, compare with <> operators or create Intl.Collator only once.



const items = [{"published_meta": null}, {"published_meta": "2006-10-16"}, {"published_meta": "2006-10-15"}];

items.sort(({published_meta: a}, {published_meta: b}) => (a ??= '0') > (b ??= '0') ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0);

console.log(items);




You need the ? on published_meta, too. published_meta?.localeCompare. Can’t call localeCompare on null.
That’s the first step. I suspect sorting using null will lead to unexpected behavior.
